# How to get Entity Framework Core 6.0.1 from daily builds

Tags: entity-framework-core, nuget, .net-6.0

I upgraded to Entity Framework Core 6.0.0, but I need the fix for Issue [26632](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26632) which is flagged as fixed for 6.0.1 and is said to be included in the Daily Builds; I followed the instructions for using [Daily Builds](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/docs/DailyBuilds.md) in the docs (I also changed dotnet7 to dotnet6), but I don't see any versions with "6.0.1-*"; Am I missing something?

Edit: Include Prerelease is checked.

nuget.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="dotnet6" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/dotnet6/nuget/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you checked `Include prerelease` checkbox? Exactly after search text box.

Comment: Are you sure there's such a version to begin with? The daily builds are for EF 7. The code for that issue was merged into the `release/6.0` branch

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Yes, I'll edit my question to include that.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Towards the bottom of the daily builds section it shows examples for dotnet6; at the bottom of the bug report ajcvickers says "@mahyar1386 The fix will be included in the 6.0.1 patch, as indicated by the milestone. The fix is already included in the latest daily build."

Comment: I'm talking about the Github repo branches, not the issue comments. The Github repo contains edits for EF 7. The merge for the fix you linked to went into `release/6.0`. What versions *do* you see in that feed?

Comment: The Daily Builds link says that new packages are published each time there's a commit to the `main` branch, not the other branches. The comment probably means that the fix was also merged in `main` and is available as the latest EF 7 package. Looking at the list of packages I only see EF7 alpha versions

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - 6.0.0-rtm.21519.8, 6.0.0-rtm.21518.9, 6.0.0-rtm.21518.6, 6.0.0-rtm.21518.4, 6.0.0-rtm.21518.2, etc...

Is there a way to find out if one of these are newer than the 6.0.0 final release?

Comment: In combobox `Package Source` select `dotnet7`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv dotnet7 just has Alpha builds of Entity Framework 7; I need the daily build of Entity Framework Core 6.

Comment: Really? I see it contains a lot of EF Core 6 releases.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I Have 6.0.0. 6.0.0-rc1.21417.12, 7.0.0-alpha.12417.16 through 7.0.0-alpha.1.21606.2; not sure why it lists 6 RC1, but that's really old, nothing that can be seen as 6.0.1. Using the dotnet6 nuget, I see 6.0.1-mauipre.1.21602.7 releases for the Microsoft.Extensions.* packages, I would assume Entity Framework would work the same way...

Comment: Well, probably best source is to create issue in EF Core repository.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23884

Look into "Issues fixed for EF Core 6.0.1 but not yet shipped"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A response from ajcvickers to my post on EF Core Issue 26632 clarified the response saying that the fix was available in the daily builds.

"Unfortunately, patches are not included in the daily builds. The 7.0.0 builds contain this fix. The patch is scheduled for release in the coming days."

Thanks to everyone who took time to help with this.

Comment: See comment to my question (I has same problem): https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26428#issuecomment-989896890

Comment: 6.0.1 is now available on Nuget!